# Problem with Taverna?

Tags: wfs, gml, svg, taverna, wsdl

I  want to  use Taverna to call an OGC WFS, and the file returned from WFS is GML, but what I want is SVG, so I have to convert GML to SVG by using Taverna. The Method I used `ExecuteProcess_gml2svg`, comes from a WSDL.

The process and the GML datasource is as shown:

[image]

The problem is when I use the datasource url in the picture (that is the 'random_points' gml datasource is http://rsg.pml.ac.uk/wps/testdata/random_points.gml), it works well, but when I download the datasource, and use Appache server in my pc to publish the same GML datasource (the url is like http://chenhongyan.com/random_points.gml), the process does not work, and the errors are:

```
Processor 'ExecuteProcess_gml2svg_2' - Port 'ProcessOutputs': 
An error occurred invoking the WSDL service
<ows:Exception xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" 
 xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode" locator="None">
 <ows:ExceptionText>
 object of type 'exceptions.IOError' has no len()
 </ows:ExceptionText>
```

and I just don't know what can I do to solve it.Can you help me?